# Understanding this SQL Query

Tags: sql, oracle, sql-delete

I'm new to oracle database, can some help me understand this query. This query eliminates duplicates from table.

```
DELETE FROM table_name A 
 WHERE ROWID > (SELECT min(rowid) 
                  FROM table_name B 
                 WHERE A.key_values = B.key_values);
```

**Any suggestions for improving the query are welcome.**

**Edit**: No this is not homework , what I didn't understand is, what is being done by subquery and what does `ROWID > On` subquery do ?

[This is the Source](http://www.orafaq.com/faq/how_does_one_eliminate_duplicates_rows_from_a_table) of the query

Comment: What in the query dont you understand? Is this homework?

Comment: @Frederik Wordenskjold Homework police?

Comment: Nope not home work, What actually is being executed in subquery ?

Comment: you need to read up on correlated subqueries http://www.oracle-database-tips.com/oracle_subquery.html

Comment: @arex1337 That would be wasting my time. I'm asking a question, simple as that. What makes you think that anyway? Homework police police?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Dissecting the actual mechanics:

```
DELETE FROM table_name A
```

This is a standard query to delete records from the table named "table_name".  Here, it has been aliased as "A" to be referred to in the subquery.

```
WHERE ROWID >
```

This places a condition on the deletion, such that for each row encountered, the ROWID must meed a condition of being greater than..

```
            (SELECT min(rowid) 
              FROM table_name B 
             WHERE A.key_values = B.key_values)
```

This is a subquery that is correlated to the main DELETE statement. It uses the value `A.key_values` from the outside query.  So given a record from the DELETE statement, it will run this subquery to find the minimum rowid (internal record id) for all records in the same table (aliased as B now) that bear the same `key_values` value.

So, to put it together, say you had these rows

```
rowid   |  key_values
=======    ============
1          A
2          B
3          B
4          C
5          A
6          B
```

The subquery works out that the min(rowid) for each record based on ALL records with the same `key_values` is:

```
rowid   |  key_values    | min(rowid)
=======    ============    ===========
1          A               1
2          B               2
3          B               2  **
4          C               4
5          A               1  **
6          B               2  **
```

For the records marked with **`**`**, the condition

```
WHERE ROWID > { subquery }
```

becomes true, and they are deleted.

#### EDIT - additional info

This answer previously stated that ROWID increased by insertion order. That is very untrue. The truth is that `rowid is just a file.block.slot-on-block - a physical address`.

http://asktom.oracle.com/pls/apex/f?p=100:11:0::::P11_QUESTION_ID:53140678334596

Tom's *Followup   December 1, 2008 - 6am Central time zone:*

> it is quite possible that D will be "first" in the table - as it took over A's place.
>
> If rowids always "grew", than space would never be reused (that would be an implication of rowids growing always - we would never be able to reuse old space as the rowid is just a file.block.slot-on-block - a physical address)

Comment: Nice explanation. I would have shown actual samples of ROWIDs, instead of plain integers, but the concept is well explained.

Answer (score 3):

Quote [AskTom](http://asktom.oracle.com/pls/apex/f?p=100:11:0%3a%3a%3a%3aP11_QUESTION_ID:53140678334596):

> A rowid is assigned to a row upon insert and is immutable (never changing)... unless the row 
>   is deleted and re-inserted (meaning it is another row, not the same row!)

The query you provided is relying on that rowid, and deletes all the rows with a rowid value higher than the minimum one on a per `key_values` basis.  Hence, any duplicates are removed.

The subquery you provided is a correlated subquery, because there's a relationship between the table reference in the subquery, and one outside of the subquery.

Comment: It is not correct that the duplicates "after the first row inserted" will be deleted. ROWIDs are not guaranteed to rise in order of insertion; in fact often are not.

Answer (score 3):

`Rowid` is a pseudo-column that uniquely identifies each row in a table; it is numeric.

This query finds all rows in `A` where `A.key_values = B.key_values` and delete all of them but one with the minimal `rowid`. It's just a way to arbitrarily choose one duplicate to preserve.

Answer (score 1):

`ROWID` is a number that increments for each new row that is inserted. So if you have two `ROWID` numbers 16 & 24, you know 16 was inserted before 24. Your `delete` statement is deleting all duplicates, keeping only the first of those duplicates that was inserted. Make sense??

Comment: -1 This is incorrect. ROWID takes a particular format, and often does not "increment for each new row". see for example http://alexzeng.wordpress.com/2008/10/15/oralce-physical-rowid-structure/

Comment: Thanks for the correction. For the case it is enough that it uniquely identifies a row and is comparable (has strict order).